# drawing bar chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to draw a bar chart with Chart.js. Just can't get anything to show on the screen, no error message showing. What am I doing wrong?

cdn https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js

```
<script>
var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
new Chart(income).Bar(barData);
var barData = {
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "#48A497",
        strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
        data : [456,479,324,569,702,600]
    },
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(73,188,170,0.4)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(72,174,209,0.4)",
        data : [364,504,605,400,345,320]
    }

]
} 
</script>

<canvas id="income" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *barData* data object should be defined before you use it, at the top, like this:

```
var barData = {
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "#48A497",
        strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
        data : [456,479,324,569,702,600]
    },
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(73,188,170,0.4)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(72,174,209,0.4)",
        data : [364,504,605,400,345,320]
    }

]
};

var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
new Chart(income).Bar(barData);
```

http://jsbin.com/yoguzuwoha/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can't load your your chart before barData, no need to change any thing only load your chart after barData..

```
var barData = {
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
datasets : [
{
    fillColor : "#48A497",
    strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
    data : [456,479,324,569,702,600]
},
{
    fillColor : "rgba(73,188,170,0.4)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(72,174,209,0.4)",
    data : [364,504,605,400,345,320]
}

]
};

var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
new Chart(income).Bar(barData);
```